# Using utimes or futimes to set access time and modify time separately

Tags: c, linux, api

How do I call utimes or futimes in a way that makes it ignore either the first or second times array argument.

i.e.

```
int utimes(const char *filename, const struct timeval times[2]);

struct timeval {
    long tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long tv_usec;       /* microseconds */
};
```

I remember figuring this out some time back.  You had to set tv_sec to a special value to make it ignore the argument.  Can anyone recall that or know how I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `utimes` interface is deprecated, and I don't know if it offers a way to do what you want. It was poorly standardized and the answer might vary between platforms. Instead you should use `utimensat` or `futimens`:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html

with the special value of `UTIME_OMIT`.